# How to find a record based on a full match of associations

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations, ruby-on-rails-5

I am making an application in which tasks can be completed by users. The tasks have an association `Requirements`. The `User` has an association `Qualifications`

The two are connected via a shared `QualificationCategory`

A `Task` has many requirements and a `User` has many `Qualifications`.

A Requirement is structured like this:

```
Requirement
- ID
- qualification_category_id
- task_type_id
- points_required
```

A Qualification is structured like this:

```
Qualification:
- ID
- qualification_category_id
- user_id
- points
```

**The problem is this:**

For a user I need to find all tasks he is allowed to complete. So i want to select all tasks from the database whose `task_type.requirements` match exactly inside the `user.qualifications`

So for each task check if the requirements match on any of the users qualifications based on qualification_category and for each requirement check if the corresponding user qualification points are higher or equal to the points required.

**Models**

```
class Requirement < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :qualification_category
  belongs_to :task_type, inverse_of: :requirements
end

class Task < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :task_type
  belongs_to :data_sourceable, polymorphic: true, optional: true
  belongs_to :user_id, optional: true
  belongs_to :solution, class_name: 'Hypothesis', optional: true
  belongs_to :payment_period, optional: true

  has_many :worker_groups, through: :task_type
  has_many :requirements, through: :task_type
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :timeoutable, :confirmable, :lastseenable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :registerable

  has_and_belongs_to_many :roles
  has_and_belongs_to_many :worker_groups
  has_many :payment_periods
  has_many :qualifications, inverse_of: :user
  has_many :qualification_categories, through: :qualifications
end

class Qualification < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :qualification_category
  belongs_to :user, inverse_of: :qualifications
end
```

How do i write my MySQL query or ARel statement to accomplish this. The application will hold millions of tasks so doing this in ruby is not desirable.

db fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2jBx1gQhzqn1hYS5xD82n/0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To return all `task` that a specific `user` is qualified for (based on matching a single qualification) a MySQL query something like this:

```
SELECT t.id
  FROM task t 
  JOIN task_type tt
    ON tt.id = t.task_type_id
  JOIN requirement r
    ON r.task_type_id = tt.id
  JOIN qualification q
    ON q.qualification_category_id = r.qualification_category_id
   AND q.points                   >= r.points_required
  JOIN user u
    ON u.id = q.user_id
 WHERE u.id = ?
```

This might return "duplicates"; so we could either add a GROUP BY clause, or change the join operations into EXISTS predicates.

---

To match only tasks where *all* of the requirements are satisfied by user qualification, we'd need something a little different:

```
SELECT t.id
  FROM task t
  JOIN task_type tt
    ON tt.id = t.task_type_id
 WHERE EXISTS
       ( SELECT 1
           FROM requirement r
           JOIN qualification q
             ON q.qualification_category_id = r.qualification_category_id
            AND q.points                   >= r.points_required
          WHERE r.task_type_id = tt.id
            AND q.user_id = ?                                 -- specific user
       )
   AND NOT EXISTS
       ( SELECT 1
           FROM requirement r
           LEFT
           JOIN qualification q
             ON q.qualification_category_id = r.qualification_category_id
            AND q.user_id = ?                                 -- specific user
          WHERE r.task_type_id = tt.id
            AND ( q.user_id IS NULL OR q.points < r.points_required )
       )
```

The `EXISTS` bit checks that the user has at least one qualification that meets a requirement.

The `NOT EXISTS` bit checks if there are any `requirement` for a task category  where a user does not have a matching `qualification`.

---

Thinking about this a little more, I think the `EXISTS` part could be omitted, we only need to check `NOT EXISTS`... are there any `requirement` which is not statisfied by a `qualification`.

```
SELECT t.id
  FROM task t
  JOIN task_type tt
    ON tt.id = t.task_type_id
 WHERE NOT EXISTS
       ( SELECT 1
           FROM requirement r
           LEFT
           JOIN qualification q
             ON q.qualification_category_id = r.qualification_category_id
            AND q.user_id = ?                                 -- specific user
          WHERE r.task_type_id = tt.id
            AND ( q.user_id IS NULL OR q.points < r.points_required )
       )
```

(This assumes that `qualification.points` and `requirement.points_required` are non null, so the inequality comparison will evaluate to TRUE.  If we have the possibility of NULL values, we will need to handle those appropriately.)

Comment: `Unknown column 'r.task_type' in 'where clause` i update it to task_type_id correct?

Comment: should be `r.task_type_id`.  I don't have a set of tables or example data to test against, so all you're getting is some ideas. Consider setting up a SQLFiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/ with tables and example data... i'm guessing at some column names, guessing at the datatype of `points` and `points_required`, et al.

Comment: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2jBx1gQhzqn1hYS5xD82n/0 this link has seed data and the structure

Comment: I think the condition that compares points to points_required needs to be moved the WHERE clause instead of the ON clause for the outer join (my bad). SQL in answer is updated with that change.

Answer (score 0):

To add on to spencers answer, for those looking to incorporate this into their rails project via a scope and ARel.

```
scope :qualified_for, ->(user) {
    task_types = TaskType.arel_table
    requirements = Requirement.arel_table
    qualifications = Qualification.arel_table
    requirements_conditions = requirements[:task_type_id].eq(task_types[:id])
                                  .and(
                                      qualifications[:user_id].eq(nil).or(qualifications[:points].lt(requirements[:points_required]))
                                  )

    requirement_query = Requirement.select(1).joins("LEFT
               JOIN qualifications
                 ON qualifications.qualification_category_id = requirements.qualification_category_id
                AND qualifications.user_id = #{user.id}").where(requirements_conditions).exists.not

    joins(:task_type).where(requirement_query)
  }
```